# How to create a .deb package for a Qt programme?

Tags: package-management, packaging, deb

The past few days I have been trying, without success, to create a deb package for a programme with a Qt interface. The previous steps I have done so far:

1. Created a gpg key and registered it at Launchpad;
2. Identified myself with the `DEBEMAIL` and `DEBFULLNAME` variables in `~/.bashrc`;
3. Checked out the source code from GitHub;
4. Successfully built the programme (it uses `qmake` to generate a `Makefile`), identifying all its dependencies;
5. Created a source folder including the `Makefile`, plus a `.desktop` file and an `.xpm` icon.
6. Created a tarball from this folder named *packagename-version.tar.gz*.

With this preparatory work I have tried to follow two different guides:

- [The official Ubuntu packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) - it concludes successfully, but the final `.deb` file only includes the `doc` folder.
- [A more detailed guide from xpressrazor](https://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/creating-ubuntu-packages/) - which fails when running `debuild`, with the following cryptic messages:

  `make: *** [build] Error 2
  dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
  debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
  dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed`

These and other guides out there invariably present simple examples where the programme to package is composed by a single source file (sometimes it is only a bash script). I suspect they are too simplistic for a proper programme with an elaborate GUI. In this case, what are the precise steps from `dh_make` onwards?

**Update I**: I posted to PasteBin an anonymised version of the [full `debuild` output](http://pastebin.com/Y2NtAFqK).

**Update II**: The [debuild output](http://pastebin.com/0GsF8XD1), now with `DH_VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: Could you post the full log? it seems there are some details about the errors up in the log. The portion you mention is just a resume.

Comment: Could you try again with `export DH_VERBOSE=1` uncommented or add it if is not in the `debian/rules` files. The build fails at `dh_auto_configure` step. exactly trying to run `qmake -makefile -nocache ...` . You may also try running that command directly to see if it will raise some errors.

Comment: Apparently, `qmake` is simply printing the help page and quitting without executing (I get the same in the command line). If there is a `Makefile` present already, why is `qmake` being run again?

Comment: There is an obvious reason why `qmake` is failing: no `.pro` file is given in that long command.

Comment: Qt is already using `CMake`, would you try with `dh` and `CMake` instead of `cdbs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As it happens](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2310533&p=13425998#post13425998), `dh` can not possibly be used to package a Qt programme in the traditional way presented in most guides and tutorials out there. More specifically, the `rules` file must be informed of which snippets it must use to include in the final `Makefile`.

One way of achieving this is using the `cdbs` package:

`sudo apt-get install cdbs`

Then the `rules` file must be edited to include the snippets from this package:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk
include /usr/share/cdbs/1/class/qmake.mk
```

These should be the only contents in the `rules` file, any direct references to `dh` must be removed or commented out.

At this time, `debuild` should be operational, it can be run like:

`debuild -S`